# Oauth 2 Generic Provider Template Examples

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, botframework

Looking over the possible connection provider in Azure Portal, I've determined that my use case requires the the "OAuth 2 Generic Provider" (rather than the "Generic OAuth 2" provider). However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how the templating should work or what variables are passed to the template.

I'm attempting to setup a connection with Azure DevOps. First I tried using the "Generic OAuth 2" provider and the test flow works up until the botframework's token service receives the authorization code from Azure DevOps. It'll redirect me to a "Bad Request" page. I can take the authorization code from the redirected url and construct the token call as Azure DevOps' documentation describes and it works correctly so I'm guessing this is an issue with how the botframework's token service is calling Azure DevOps hence why I need to use the "OAuth 2 Generic Provider" since it allows me to specify how the token service calls Azure DevOps.

Ideally, this would be added to the documentation somewhere or - even better - as hints on the Azure portal page.

Edit: Added a screenshot of the page. What do you put in the "Template" fields on that form?

[image: Specifically, what do I put in the "Template" fields in this form?]

Comment: How are you handling the Auth flow? Can you post your code?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. There is no code, I'm just trying to fill out that form correctly.

Comment: It's possible that you can use the 'Generic Oauth 2' instead of 'Oauth 2 Generic Provider', so you can skip all this. It really depend on how you're handling the auth.

Comment: I tried that before. What I think is happening with that is the `client_assertion_type` and `grant_type` might not be set correctly and Azure DevOps is 400'ing the token request. Also, even if it were possible to work around this issue, why is there no documentation for something that's supported in the UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a hold of the team behind that form. Commenting here for anyone that searches for something similar on Google.

These are the values that worked for me, you'll need to set your own id/secrets/scopes

- Scope List Delimiter: `,`
- Authorization URL Template: `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize`
- Authorization URL Query String Template: `?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=Assertion&state={State}&scope={Scopes}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}`
- Token URL Template: `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token`
- Token URL Query String Template: `?`
- Token Body Template: `client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion={ClientSecret}&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={Code}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}`
- Refresh URL Template: `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token`
- Refresh URL Query String Template: `?`
- Refresh Body Template: `client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion={ClientSecret}&grant_type=refresh_token&assertion={RefreshToken}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}`

Answer (score 0):

These are the values I used when setting up auth with Azure AD/Entra ID (multi-tenant logins).

I configured the "OAuth 2 Generic Provider" with the following settings, and it worked effectively:

- **Scope list delimiter**: `,`
- **Authorization URL template**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
- **Authorization URL query string template**: `?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&state={State}&scope={Scopes}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}`
- **Token URL template**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- **Token URL query string template**: `?`
- **Token body template**: `grant_type=authorization_code&code={Code}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&scope={Scopes}`
- **Refresh URL template**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- **Refresh URL query string template**: `?`
- **Refresh body template**: `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={RefreshToken}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&scope={Scopes}`
- **Scopes**: `profile openid`

These settings should align with your requirements for the "OAuth 2 Generic Provider".