# BotFramework integration with PingFederate over OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, pingfederate

I am trying to implement a ms teams bot (using C#) and one of the requirement is to authenticate the "bot" itself with ping identity provider over OAuth 2.0. Now I have been following the documentation for botframework as well as ping identity but I do not find anything specific that describes about integration of botframework with ping identity provider. I believe I should use "Generic Oauth 2" to integrate the pingfederate with my bot but I don't seem to get the right resources to follow. If anybody could guide me or point towards the right resources, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may or may not help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676376/oauth-2-generic-provider-template-examples