# Is it possible to overload the 'state' parameter in botbuilder-dialog OAuthPrompt flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using the botbuilder-dialog OAuthPrompt class in my teams app to create a signin flow for my custom OAuth service.

(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/oauthprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest)

As part of this flow we create the dialog:

```js
 this.addDialog(
      new dialogs.OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
        connectionName,
        text: 'Please sign in so I can show you your profile.',
        title: 'Sign in',
        timeout: 300000,
      }),
    )
```

We have defined a Generic OAuth 2 service in Azure OAuth connection settings.  And this works fine.

The PATH that is sent to my service is:

```
/oauth/authorize?client_id=<redacted>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftoken.botframework.com%2f.auth%2fweb%2fredirect&scope=read+write&state=89c54fc705a649fe8a2be3feacbbe89e
```

the `state` param in the query string here is likely a randomly generated GUID.  I need to override this state for my application however, as I have a need to receive the tenant_id of the teams server and i'd like to include this in the state param.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: FWIW -- I did see this helpful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676376/oauth-2-generic-provider-template-examples which outlines configuration of a more flexible version of the oauth generic provider.  But, here again, the `State` param seems hard-code.

Comment: Could you please explain where exactly are you using tenant id and for what purpose. Tenant id is already a part of the bot payload.

Comment: We would like to include it as part of the state in the oauth authorize URL so that we can dispatch from tenant-id to the correct oauth service.  We have an architecture with a single service that fronts all of our backend client servers.  We would redirect to the correct backend OAuth server based on the tenant id.

Comment: Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab#:~:text=The%20OAuth%202.0%20implicit%20grant%20flow%20calls%20for%20a%20state,grants%20access%20to%20the%20tab) it may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Mamatha-MSFT.  We have decided to give up on running our own OAuth service for now and just use Azure AD authentication with our modals and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Teams opens the start page in an iframe in a pop-up window. The start page generates random state data, saves it for future validation, and redirects to the identity provider's /authorize endpoint, such as https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize for Azure AD. Replace  with your own tenant id that is context.tid. Similar to other application auth flows in Teams, the start page must be on a domain that is in its validDomains list, and on the same domain as the post sign in redirect page.