# Azure Bot Oauth 2 Generic Provider URL Template parameters

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, bots, botframework, subdomain

I'm trying to build an Azure bot right now with OAuth 2.0 set up with my application. I found that there is an *Oauth 2 Generic Provider*, which seems to be the closest to what I need. The issue is that my application is multi-tenanted with each tenant having a different subdomain in the URL (eg. tenant1.test.com, tenant2.test.com).

The example that I've found ([Oauth 2 Generic Provider Template Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676376/oauth-2-generic-provider-template-examples)) has a static URL in the **URL Template** fields, but I'm wondering if it's possible to pass in a custom **subdomain** parameter, while having a URL Template like `https://{subdomain}.test.com/oauth/authorize`.

The documentation around the Oauth2 Generic Provider is pretty sparse, so I'm not sure if parameters are only available for query strings (and not the URL template) or if there are only a few fixed parameters that are available.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but from my experience this is not possible. I've never seen any doc reference this as being an option, unfortunately. I would suggest you ask your question in the MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html) forum. It's active with pretty good response times (generally). The hard part will be deciding which tag(s) to append to it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the authentication URL, we need to use the parameters like Client ID. Instead of using the subdomain directly, we can add that sub-domain URL as the trusted URL and pass it to the specific client directly in the resource section.

[image]
[image]

Fill the details which are required and can add the subdomain indirectly.